# How to perform side-effect inside of an epic in redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-saga, redux-observable

In `redux-observable`, epics are accepting stream of actions and returning back new stream of actions. In my use-case I need to send analytics event after some action was dispatched and do nothing after.

With `redux-saga`, I can just listen that action using `takeEvery`, and perform a side-effect inside of a saga function:

```
function* saga() {
  yield takeEvery('SOME_ACTION', function*() {
    sendAnalytics();
  })
}
```

But how can I achieve the same with `redux-observable`? There is pretty much side effects, that are not requiring dispatching new actions, like initializing plugins, logging, setting cookies etc...

If it's an anti-pattern for both of these libraries, what solution should be used for these kinds of effects?

Comment: I haven't used either `redux-saga` or `redux-observable`, but I've done this particular side effect of tracking by just calling the analytics module inside of `mapDispatchToProps`, which is a legitimate place to do this in my opinion. So before or after you call `dispatch` you just do something like `googleAnalytics.trackEvent(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, but in my opinion, `mapDispatchToProps` functions is not the right place to perform side-effects

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Definitely not an anti-pattern outright to have an epic which is "read-only"--but I want to caution that it's often a sign a person is doing something less-than-idiomatic, but this is not one of those cases.

There are likely many ways of accomplishing this in Rx. Here are two:

### do + ignoreElements

I think this is the most clear of what it does. `do` is only ever used to perform a side effect (often logging) for next/error/complete without affecting the stream. We then use `ignoreElements` to prevent the `SOME_ACTION` from being dispatched again (which would cause infinite recursion). [See the rxjs docs for more info on these operators](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/)

```
const someEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType('SOME_ACTION')
    .do(() => sendAnalytics())
    .ignoreElements();
```

### Anonymous Observable

This is a somewhat more "lightweight" solution since it doesn't use any operators other than `ofType`. I would caution against using this one though until you and your teammates have a solid grasp of RxJS and particularly creating custom/anonymous Observables. i.e. don't write code you don't understand.

```
const someEpic = action$ =>
  new Observable(() =>
    action$.ofType('SOME_ACTION')
      .subscribe(() => sendAnalytics()) // subscription is returned so it can be cleaned up
  );
```

---

This use case would be a great addition to the Recipes section of the docs, if someone ever has the time to PR it.

---

Btw, this is mostly an RxJS question where the stream just happens to be actions. You might find you get answers and better support long-term if you search or phrase your questions in the context of RxJS instead of redux-observable. Nearly all redux-observable questions are actually RxJS questions, which is great cause the knowledge is transferable!

Comment: I'd just like to say, I really appreciate the thought and effort you put into clearly and completely answering redux-observable questions, @jayphelps!    I not only learn redux-observable, but also valuable RxJS tips.  So, thanks!

Comment: Why do you use ignoreElements instead of NEVER? Which one is better?

Comment: @Fen1kz `never()` is a static Observable _factory_--it returns a source Observable that never emits, never completes, never errors. `ignoreElements()` on the other hand is an _operator_--meaning it operates on another source observable rather than being a static producer itself--that when applied to an Observable will simply ignore any values that source Observable emits. So not the same :) `ignoreElements()` will NOT ignore errors/complete.